# What formula relates the factorial of a product to the product of factorials?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, factorial, natural-numbers

#### $\text{We want } \, (a \cdot b)! = \text{some formula in terms of } (a!) \text{ and } (b!)$

---

Let $F$ be a mapping from $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{N}, \quad (a\cdot b)! = F(a! \, , b!)$

Is there a nice closed-form formula for $F$ which does not directly refer to the gamma function, or inverse gamma function?

Comment: Why do you think there should be one?  Even for $b=2$, for large $a, (2a)! \gg a!$

Comment: @RossMillikan The fact that $(2*a)!$ is much much larger than $(a!)$ does not mean that there is no simple formula we can use to describe $(2*a)!$. Note that $(2*a)^{2*a}$ is even bigger and there is a nice simple formula for $(2a)^{2a}$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the gamma function in place of the factorial, there is Gauss multiplication formula (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5))

$$\Gamma(ab)=(2 \pi )^{\frac{1-a}{2}}\, a^{a b-\frac{1}{2}}\,\prod_{k=0}^{a-1}\Gamma \left(b+\frac{k}{a}\right)$$

But$$(ab)!=\Gamma(ab+1)=ab \,\Gamma(ab)$$ then
$$(ab)!=(2 \pi )^{\frac{1-a}{2}}\, a^{a b+\frac{1}{2}}b\,\prod_{k=0}^{a-1}\Gamma \left(b+\frac{k}{a}\right)$$ and you can again transform the gamma function in terms of factorials.